# MySQL coalesce function is not working as Expected

Tags: mysql

The below query is not returning correct *startDowntime*. I recently migrated the Database to latest MYSQL version. the same query was working fine in my previous DB version.

The *startDowntime* should show anything which falls between the range or return `null`. The actual output I receive is not within the range. Its returning the minimum DateTime which is available in DB.

```
SELECT a.service_name, a.status,
   (CASE 
     WHEN a.status = "Down" THEN a.time_stamp 
     WHEN a.status = "Up" THEN COALESCE(
       (
         select b.time_stamp from service_status b
         where b.status = "Down" and b.time_stamp < a.time_stamp 
           and b.time_stamp >= '2016-08-07 22:00' 
           and b.service_name = a.service_name 
           and b.environment = a.environment
         order by b.time_stamp desc 
         limit 1
       ) , null 
     ) END
   ) AS  startDowntime,
   (CASE
     WHEN a.status = "Up" THEN a.time_stamp
     WHEN a.status = "Down" THEN COALESCE(
       (
         select b.time_stamp from service_status b
         where b.status = "Up" and b.time_stamp > '2016-08-07 22:00' 
           and b.service_name = a.service_name 
           and b.environment = a.environment
         order by b.time_stamp asc limit 1
       ), NOW()
     ) END
   ) AS endDowntime
FROM service_status a
WHERE a.time_stamp >= '2016-08-07 22:00' 
  AND a.time_stamp <= '2016-08-12 18:00' 
  AND a.environment = 'QA3'
GROUP BY a.service_name, startDowntime
```

Table Definition is

CREATE TABLE service_status ( 
time_stamp timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, 
environment varchar(20) NOT NULL, 
service_name varchar(40) NOT NULL, 
interface_name varchar(40) NOT NULL, 
description varchar(100), 
monitoring_method varchar(50), 
status varchar(10), 
is_stub varchar(10) DEFAULT N, 
CONSTRAINT PRIMARY PRIMARY KEY (time_stamp,environment,service_name)
 ) ;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX PRIMARY ON service_status ( time_stamp, environment, service_name ) ; 
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX PRIMARY_IDX001 ON service_status ( time_stamp, environment, service_name, interface_name ) ;

### Expected Output

```
status|service_name|startDowntime|endDowntime  
------|------------|-------------|-----------  
Up    |COUPONVAL   |null         |2016-08-09 12:45:01.0
```

### Actual output

```
status|service_name|startDowntime         |endDowntime
------|------------|----------------------|-----------  
Up    |COUPONVAL   |2014-09-23 10:32:00.0 |2016-08-09 12:45:01.0
```

Table definition is

CREATE TABLE service_status
(
   time_stamp timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
   environment varchar(20) NOT NULL,
   service_name varchar(40) NOT NULL,
   interface_name varchar(40) NOT NULL,
   description varchar(100),
   monitoring_method varchar(50),
   status varchar(10),
   is_stub varchar(10) DEFAULT N,
   CONSTRAINT PRIMARY PRIMARY KEY (time_stamp,environment,service_name)
)
;
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX PRIMARY ON service_status
(
  time_stamp,
  environment,
  service_name
)
;
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX PRIMARY_IDX001 ON service_status
(
  time_stamp,
  environment,
  service_name,
  interface_name
)
;

Comment: What are you trying to do with `COALESCE`? You're saying is to return the largest time_stamp based on the criteria, and if it doesn't exist return null? This defeats the purpose of `COALESCE`. http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/coalesce-function.php . I'd get rid of the `COALESCE` and run again

Comment: Thanks for your response!! if I replace null with real value '2016-08-07 22:00', its still giving me the same actual output. as per above "where clause" it shouldn't fetch the min value for startDowntime.

Comment: Id say that's because the subquery within the `COALESCE` function isn't returning `null`. I suspect it's an issue with the `GROUP BY`. I'd remove it or add `status` to it, because it may be messing with the results that are being returned

Comment: This seems to be an issue due to DB migration. I dropped my migrated table and recreated the table in newer MYSQL. Exported same data to new table. After these steps, My query is running fine. Thanks for your time and suggestions tomb!!